# Xamarin.Forms Chat App Messages Right Left Position

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I made an app for test something in FireBase and actually i created a chat app. But i want to show messages like a whatsapp when i send message looking right side. If i get message looking left side. Actually i dont need complication. So i have users for chatting. This users can login and join chat.

So basicly my chatting page XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="4*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        
    <ListView Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding .}" x:Name="_lstChat"
            SeparatorVisibility="None">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
    <TextCell Text="{Binding UserName}" Detail="{Binding UserMessage}" DetailColor="Fuchsia" />                 
    </DataTemplate>

            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1" RowSpacing="5">

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            
    <Entry Placeholder="Write Message .." Grid.Column="0" x:Name="_etMessage"/>
    <Button Text="Send!" Grid.Column="1" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

i dont need to use TextCell i just want to need left and right position.

```
public partial class ChattingPage : ContentPage
{
    Scripts.FireBase db = new Scripts.FireBase();
    Model.Room rm = new Model.Room();
    public ChattingPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (Preferences.Get("AdminCheck", string.Empty)== "1")
        {
            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<ChatPage, Model.Room>(this, "RoomProp", async (page, data) =>
            {
                rm = data;

                _lstChat.BindingContext = await db.subChat(data.Name);
                

                MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<ChatPage, Model.Room>(this, "RoomProp");

            });
        }else
        {
            SubList();
        }

    }

    void Button_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var chatOBJ = new Model.Chat { UserMessage = _etMessage.Text, UserName = Preferences.Get("RandomText", string.Empty) };
        if(Preferences.Get("AdminCheck", string.Empty) == "1")
        {
            db.saveMessage(chatOBJ, rm.Name);
        }
        else
        {
            db.saveMessage(chatOBJ, Preferences.Get("RandomText", string.Empty));
        }

        _etMessage.Text = "";

    }

    async void SubList()
    {
        _lstChat.BindingContext = await db.subChat(Preferences.Get("RandomText", string.Empty));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a property to message, for example of type bool, which will determine if the message is incoming or outgoing. Then create a converter that will return a horizontal LayoutOption alignment based on this value, left (Start) for incoming messages and right (End) for outgoing ones. Set this horizontal alignment via the converter with the message type value to the bubble displaying the message text.

Comment: Thank you for reply.

actually i try to use DataTemplateSelector in xamarin but if i use selector getting error. When i use same code in selector for listview.itemtemplate code is working. Everythink is ready but its not work...

and your idea very good but how can i use this codes?